# Perl Text processing on a variable before its usage

Tags: perl

I wrote a perl script whihc will output a list containing similar entries like below:

```
$var = ' whatever'
```

$var contains: a single quote, a space, the word **whatever**, single quote

actually, this is key of a hash and i want to pull the value for the same. but due to the single quotes and a space in betweene, i am not able to pull the hash key value.

So, i want to strip $var as below:

```
$var = whatever
```

meaning remove the single quote, the space and the trailing single quote.

so that I can use $var as hash key to pull the respective value.

could you guide me on a perl oneliner for the same.

thnaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$string = "' my string'";
print $string . "\n";
$string =~ s/'//g;
$string =~ s/^ //g;
print $string;
```

**Output**

```
' my string'
my string
```

Comment: Perfect. this is working fine and I ma able to pull the hash values now. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is several ways to do it, but beware - modifying the keys in a hash can end with unwanted results, like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $src = {
    "a a"       => 1,
    " a a "     => 2,
    "' a a '"   => 3,
};
print "src: ", Dumper($src);
my $trg;

@$trg{ map { s/^[\s']*(.*?)[\s']*$/$1/; $_ } keys %$src } = values %$src;
print "copy: ", Dumper($trg);
```

will produce:

```
src: $VAR1 = {
          ' a a ' => 2,
          '\' a a \'' => 3,
          'a a' => 1
        };
copy: $VAR1 = {
          'a a' => 1
        };
```

Any regex is possible do explain with YAPE::Regex::Explain module. (from CPAN). For the above regex:

```
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new( qr(^[\s']*(.*?)[\s']*$) )->explain;
```

will produce:

The regular expression:

```
(?-imsx:^[\s']*(.*?)[\s']*$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\s']*                   any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                           \f, and " "), ''' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\s']*                   any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                           \f, and " "), ''' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In short the: `s/^[\s']*(.*?)[\s']*$/$1/;` mean:

- at the beginning of the string match whitespaces or apostrophe as much times is possible,
- then match anything
- match at the end of string whitespaces or apostrophes as much times as possible
- and keep the only the "anything" part

Comment: aah, he regex stuff in your code too complicated for me to understand. i will try decoding it later. thanks. for the time being, the solution given by cppcoder is working for me.

Comment: This is awesome. I was not aware of **YAPE::Regex::Explain**. In my perl scripts, I have using regex for quite some time, some I have written my self and others copied from google without understanding how it works. Now I think i will be able to decode and understand the perl regex. I can't thank you enough. I really Appreciate your time on the regex explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var =~ tr/ '//d;
```

see: [tr operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

or, by regex

```
$var =~ s/(?:^['\s]+)|'//g;
```

The latter will keep the spaces in the middle of the word, the former removes all spaces and single quotes.

A short test:

```
...
$var = q{' what ever'};
$var =~ s/
         (?:     # find the following group
           ^        # at string begin, followed by      
           ['\s]+   # space or single quote, one or more
         )       # close group
         |       # OR
         '       # single quotes in the while string 
         //gx ;  # replace by nothing, use formatted regex (x)
print "|$var|\n";
...
```

prints:

```
|what ever|
```

as expected.

Comment: The 2nd one with the regex is not working. I will give it a try later. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Dheeraj, on the type of input you provided, it works. See my added explanation. This is just the combination of the two regexes you chose in one regex.

Comment: Now I got it. thanks for the explanation. You guys are too good in regex.